# I have a register code for tax evading, but it just don't work... Can you guys help me?

Tags: c

My code is supposed to registry a tax envasion, but i can't acess the variables of the structs to compare the Strings and execute the code... The parts that make part of the error:

```
typedef struct{
//Struct para definição da residencia
int numRes, inadAtiva, inadCad;
struct residente *infoRes;
struct local endereco;
struct inad *inadimplencia;
}residencia;

struct local{
    char rua[50], estado[2], cidade[50];
    int numIdent, cep;
};

void cadInad(){
    int numCasa, loop;
    double valor;
    char rua[50];
    
    printf("Informe o endereço da residência: ");
    scanf("%s", &rua);
    printf("Informe o número da casa: ");
    scanf("%i", &numCasa);
    
for(loop = 0; loop < max; loop++){
    if(strcmp(rua, residencia[loop].endereco.*rua) == 0 && numCasa == residencia.numRes);
    *residencia[loop].inadAtiva++;
    *residencia[loop].inadCad++;
    printf("Digite o valor da inadimplencia: ");
    scanf("%f", &residencia[loop].inadimplencia.valor);
    printf("Digite o ano e o mês da inadimplência: ");
    scanf("%i%i", &residencia[loop].inadimplencia.ano, &residencia[i].inadimplencia.mes);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to define `struct local` before you can refer to it in the `residencia` struct.

Comment: `residencia` isn't a variable, it's a typedef. You can't use `residencia[loop]`